# Attach an internal storage encoded bitmap string in email

Tags: android, email, bitmap, sharedpreferences

I'm writing and reading an image as a string in my internal storage. Both methods are below:

```
public static void writeImageInternalStorage( Bitmap bitmap, Context context ){
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();

        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences( context );
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit       = sharedPreferences.edit();
        edit.putString( "sequence_password_boxes",encodedImage );
        edit.apply();
    }

    public static Bitmap readImageInternalStorage( Context context ){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences( context );
        String storedImage = sharedPreferences.getString( "sequence_password_boxes", "");
        if( !storedImage.equalsIgnoreCase( "" ) ){
            byte[] b = Base64.decode(storedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
            return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Works fine. I need to attach the read image from internal stoge to an email. Previosly I have success when image comes from external storage:

```
File file = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), context.getString( R.string.screenshot_name ) );
    if( file.exists() || file.canRead() ){
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile( file );
        sendIntent.putExtra( Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri );
    }
```

In my new case I can't pass filepath to Uri. And I believe I need to decode image to attach it properly.
Do I need to get the internal storage filepath and after that decode image? This case can't be possible because an Uri needs a stream.
What can I do?

Comment: `Attach an internal storage encoded bitmap string in email`. Well wrong subject as you store in shared preferences. Not in internal storage. Moreover you are not storing a bitmap but a jpg image base64 encoded.

Comment: I wonder why you use shared preferences to store a jpg file. Bad practise. You should just write the jpg 'to disk'.

Comment: @greenapps My First approach was write on disk. I'm doing that because I don't know when  email will be senti. My ideal scenario is after email is sent the imagem  is deleted. But gmail activity doesn't trigger any evento for this.